# What is the status of a result of Kontsevich and Rosenberg?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, derived-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry

In their influential paper *Noncommutative Smooth Spaces* (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9812158), Kontsevich and Rosenberg define the notion of a noncommutative projective space.  In Section 3.3 they state a theorem which says these spaces satisfy a version of Beilinson's theorem.  Since this paper has been written, Rosenberg has written a number of long (and unrefereed) papers describing the construction of these noncommutative projective spaces (and more generally, noncommutative Grassmannians), but as far as I can tell, a formal proof of the aforementioned fact from  Section 3.3 of "Noncommutative Smooth Spaces" has not appeared in any format.

My question is:
**Does a proof of Beilinson's theorem for noncommutative projective spaces stated in Section 3.3 of "Noncommutative Smooth Spaces" appear in print?**  **If not, does anyone know the reason its proof has not appeared?**